# Spring Boot. How to implement timeouts between specific method requests for user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The controller has 2 methods:

```
Operation updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations() {
  // heavy logic
}
Operation updateReallyHeavyRefundOperations() {
  // heavy logic
}
```

> What I want to achieve is this: When user requests one of those
> methods, there must be a timeout before it's allowed for user to call
> the same method again. For example, if I call
> updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations(), I have to wait 10 seconds before
> calling updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations() again. And if I call
> updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations(), I can call
> updateReallyHeavyRefundOperations() without need to wait.

The best solution seems to implement this on frontend, but we're not allowed to add there any timeouts, button blocking or etc for those methods.

I see the following solutions:

- Use ReentrantLock to lock and unlock when request is finished for example.
- Store in a Map the last request time of the method. And return null or throw Exception, for request in timeout.

The time for request of those methods execution is long(~ 3m). Using the first approach, that seems as a problem, considering nothing interferes if user
will click on button with updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations() for 100 times for example. There will be 100 locked requests waiting for their execution and dramatically decreasing Tomcat
performance. But at least it will prevent from executing the logic of the new user request, before the last finished. Second approach looks better, but is there a more Spring-way to address this problem and add a controller method timeout for same user?

First approach:

```
@Target( value = {ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BlockUserRequestIfTimeout {
}

public class BlockUserRequestIfTimeoutAspect {

    private Map<String, ReentrantLock> lockMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Around("@annotation(BlockUserRequestIfTimeout)")
    public void blockRequest(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {

        String id = "someId"; // get custom id from Jwt token
        log.debug("Block User Aspect called");
        lockExecution(id, () -> {
            try {
                point.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private Lock getLock(String id) {
        ReentrantLock lock = lockMap.get(id);
        if (lock == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                lock = lockMap.get(id);

                if (lock == null) {
                    lock = new ReentrantLock();
                    lockMap.put(id, lock);
                }
            }
        }
        return lock;
    }

    private void lockExecution(String id, Runnable runnable) {
        Lock lock = getLock(id);
        try {
            lock.lockInterruptibly();
            log.debug("id: [{}] locked, thread: [{}]", id, Thread.currentThread().getName());
            runnable.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
            log.debug("id: [{}] unlocked, thread: [{}]", id, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

}


public class OperationController {

   @BlockUserRequestIfTimeout
   Operation updateReallyHeavyPaymentOperations() {
     // heavy logic
  }

}
```

Comment: ReentrantLock technique can cause serious problems due to the thread pool, as you said. Storing the state in a Map seems to be a nice way to go. Just be sure to use a thread-safe structure, like `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: My two cents, I would go for an async call for this heavy method with something to check whether it is running or not. User trigger the process, system starts the task, if user request it again you can either queue the process (and say to user that is queued for processing) or inform user that there is already one running and user should try again later.

Comment: How do you want to limit this, is it per each user, or for all calls in total? Do you manage some kind of state (like a session) in the backend?

Comment: @cyberbrain, yes I would like to limit this per each user.
Yes, we can extract unique organization id from the JWT token by which we can identify user making request

Comment: So you will need to keep a state in the server by storing the timestamp when the function was called last by that user and not let him start it again before the wanted delay has passed. No concurrency magic necessary here.

Comment: Indeed that seems as a best approach, I thought there might be a built-in mechanism in Spring which would allow to do the same